# Confusion about function expressions and declarations

Tags: javascript, iife

So I was reading up the *Html 5 CSS Training guide* for a Microsoft certificate when I stumbled upon this piece of code:

CalculatorLibrary.js

```
(function () {

    this.calculatorNamespace = this.calculatorNamespace || {};
    var ns = this.calculatorNamespace;

    ns.initialize = function () {
        var calculator = new ns.Calculator();
        $("button[id^='btnNumber']").on('click', calculator.numberClick);
        $('#btnPlus').on('click', calculator.plusClick);
        $('#btnMinus').on('click', calculator.minusClick);
        $('#btnClearEntry').on('click', calculator.clearEntry);
        $('#btnClear').on('click', calculator.clear);
        calculator.clear();
    };

    ns.Calculator = (function () {

        function Calculator() {

        }

        //Some prototype code

        return Calculator;
    })();

})();
```

Now I don't get why this doesn't throw an error, when the parses reaches this line:

```
var calculator = new ns.Calculator();
```

This code is calling a function expression which at this point hasn't been read yet. Why does this work? I always thought only function declarations could be invoked before the line that they're declared.

Is this because it's an IIFE and its got some magic that is unknown to me?

EDIT:

initialize gets invoked in my index.html (bottom of body):

```
    <script src="../../../Exercise1Completed/WebCalculatorSolution/packages/jQuery.1.8.2/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/CalculatorLibrary.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                calculatorNamespace.initialize();
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: `ns.initialize` isn't actually being called

Comment: FYI, this code would produce an error in ES5 strict mode because `this` would be `undefined`.

Comment: I thought this is the global object (window) here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was calling `ns.initialize` in a script that was defined after `CalculatorLibrary.js` this caused didn't cause an error, when I moved this piece of code to the top of `CalculatorLibrary.js` I got the error I expected

Answer (score 2):

```
var calculator = new ns.Calculator();
```

is contained within the `ns.initialize` function - ie it won't get evaluated until `ns.initialize` is actually called.  By the time it is called, the following code, and therefore `ns.Calculator = ...` will have run, and be available.

Comment: I don't get it: the parser reads the file the first time, sees the iife and invokes it, inside the iife are no function declarations so ns.initialize and ns.Calculator are both undefined. The parser starts executing the code and jumps in initialize (which is executed at DOM load) and sees new ns.undefined?

Comment: `ns.initialize = function()...` _is_ a function declaration - it's not being called in the code you've posted, something else will be calling it.  It's not until that happens that it will run the contents.

Comment: @RobinHellemans I feel like you are not understanding how javascript works on a more fundamental level.  When you assign a function to a variable, that doesn't run the function. Nowhere in your code posted do you have `ns.initialize()` which is what it would take to actually run the function

Comment: I'm sorry, I didnt realize I didnt add that code, added it now

Comment: @JamesThorpe Oh wow I just realized my error, the parser passes my code twice, all functions have been defined and only then does my code get called, it is because I am doing it from another script that is loaded AFTER this script that this code is working, if I had called initialize from the beginning of `CalculatorLibrary.j`s this would have caused the error I foresaw. Though I still don't onderstand how `ns.initialize = function().. `is a function declaration and not an expression